# How to set type mappings for OpenAPI generator in build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I have the similar problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072887/openapi-gradle-serialize-deserialize-multiple-datetime-formats), however whenever I try to add my type mappings to my openApiGenerate task I'm met with the following error:

```
build.gradle': 49: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 49, column 16.
     openApiGenerate{
                    ^

  1 error
```

My task config is structured thus:

```
openApiGenerate{
    generatorName = "jaxrs-jersey"
    inputSpec = "$project.swaggerFile"
    outputDir = "$project.buildSrcRoot"
    apiPackage = "$project.apiPackage"
    invokerPackage = "$project.rootPackage"
    modelPackage = "$project.modelPackage"
    generateModelTests = false

    globalProperties = [
            apis: "",
            models: "",
            modelDocs: "false",
    ]
    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary: "java8",
            hideGenerationTimestamp: "true",
            invokerPackage: "$project.rootPackage",
            useJakartaEe: "false",
    ]

    typeMappings.set([string+date-time: "LocalDateTime"])
    importMappings.set([LocalDateTime: "java.time.LocalDateTime"])
}
```

However removing the `type` mapping resolves the issue, but is useless as the import mapping requires a type mapping to be able to achieve the desired result.
I have also not found an example beyond [my earlier link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072887/openapi-gradle-serialize-deserialize-multiple-datetime-formats) on how to add these config to the build.gradle file. 
I am using version 6.6.0 of the generator.

Comment: Have you tried to use `typeMappings = [` like `configOptions = [` not sure if `set` works with the Groovy Gradle synstax. I've used it within a build.gradle.kts
`typeMappings.set(
            mapOf(
                "integer+int16" to "kotlin.Short"
            )
        )`

Comment: Yes, it was the first format I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the `typeMappings` keys and values must be in single quotes:

```
typeMappings = ['string+date-time':'LocalDatTime']
```

Comment: Thank, but need also import  type with importMappings like this:
[code]
importMappings = [
        Long: 'java.lang.Long'
    ]
    typeMappings = ['number+int64':'Long']
[/code]